# insert text into multiple fields such as excel cells

Tags: autohotkey

I'm configuring autohotkey for the first time and am having trouble with a script to insert text into multiple fields. The syntax I'm using does not work.

```
array_CCS := []
array_ccs.insert("1100580")
array_ccs.insert("1098954")
array_ccs.insert("1032801")
array_ccs.insert("1100579")

#C::
for value in array_ccs {
send Value: %value%
}
RETURN
```

I'm inserting this into a SAP form which is similar to Excel cells. 
But nothing at all shows up even into a notepad file.

I might also have to add a line feed or return for each entry as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` returns both the key and value for each element:

```
f4::
  for key,value in array_ccs {
    send Value: %value%{ERROR}
  }
  return
```

Output when pressing F4 in notepad:

```
Value: 1100580
Value: 1098954
Value: 1032801
Value: 1100579
```

ref: [for-loop](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/For.htm)

Comment: Copied your code as is and still nothing , yet my other single text keys work fine.

Comment: I'm using version 1.1.25.02! If that makes a difference.

Comment: Other code can affect whether or not a hot key fires.  Try right-clicking the green autohotkey on your toolbar, chose "Edit this script" and replace whatever's there and save.  Save the existing code somewhere first if you need to of course. Then right click again and chose "Reload this script". Then fire up notepad and press F4.  You can also stick a MsgBox as the first statement after F4 just to make sure the hot key is enabled.

Comment: Your code works, its just that I had to put the loading of the array above the code and c#::

Answer (score 1):

You should consider looking into COM if you're going to be working with MS Office stuff. It eliminates the need to use the clunky and unreliable version of sending keystrokes.

However, here's your code. I made it a little prettier and added an enter to the end of your send.
If you're wanting to move to the right instead of the cell below, replace `{Enter}` with `{Tab}`.

Tested working with Excel.

```
array_CCS   :=  [1100580
                ,1098954
                ,1032801
                ,1100579]
return
#C::
    for value in array_ccs
        Send, % "Value: " value "{Enter}"
return
```

Links to 2 great COM guides. I'd suggest starting with Jethrow's.
[Jethrow's COM Guide](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/47052-basic-webpage-controls-with-javascript-com-tutorial/) and [Micker's Basic Ahk COM Guide](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/64563-basic-ahk-v11-com-tutorial-for-webpages/)